# Custom Windows 11 installation media made by swapping install.wim with a WIM captured from my system

Tags: windows-11, iso-image, wim, installation-media

So, I have a WIM captured from my Sysprep-ed, customized Windows 11 install + additional programs. The system drive, C:, basically. I want to be able to deploy this custom install to any of my desktop machines whenever needed.

For deployment, I could go for booting to a Windows PE environment & using DSIM, apply the WIM. But, I want something that's a little bit fancier & automated (like running the Setup.exe). Can I simply take a Windows 11 installation media ISO & replace the `%Drive%\sources\install.wim` with my own WIM?

I've skimmed through some tutorials on making your own customized Windows Installation Media & none so far have of that as simply replacing the `install.wim`, as a quick & dirty solution. Is this bad practice? Are you forgetting a lot of other things?

Comment: check out fog server

Comment: See this>>>>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/capture-and-apply-windows-using-a-single-wim?view=windows-11